# Does join operator in RxJava allow specifying windows by count?

Tags: rx-java

I'm reading this [RxJava Tutorial](https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava/blob/master/Part%204%20-%20Concurrency/3.%20Sequences%20of%20coincidence.md#join) and trying to understand the `join` operator. The signature of it is as follows:

```
public final <TRight,TLeftDuration,TRightDuration,R> Observable<R> join(
    Observable<TRight> right,
    Func1<T,Observable<TLeftDuration>> leftDurationSelector,
    Func1<TRight,Observable<TRightDuration>> rightDurationSelector,
    Func2<T,TRight,R> resultSelector)
```

And here's the example:

```
Observable<String> left = 
        Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(i -> "L" + i);
Observable<String> right = 
        Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(i -> "R" + i);

left
    .join(
        right,
        i -> Observable.timer(150, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
        i -> Observable.timer(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
        (l,r) -> l + " - " + r
    )
    .take(10)
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

1. Is it possible to join two sequences using count instead of duration? The operator `window` can be defined using either count or time.
2. What type of `Observable`s returned by `leftDurationSelector` and `rightDurationSelector`? The names suggest that they should be time related, but the signatures seem to allow any kind of `Observable`.

EDIT: I think I should give an example for the questions to be clearer:
Let say I have 2 sequences:

```
0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-|
0---2---4---6---8---|
```

I want to join them on windows of 2 elements for both sides, the windows would move like this:

```
[0]-
[0]-

[0-1]-
[0]---

 0[1-2]-
[0---2]-

 0-1[2-3]-
[0---2]---

 0-1[2-3]-
[0---2]---

 0-1-2[3-4]-
 0--[2---4]-

 0-1-2[3-4]-
 0--[2---4]-

 0-1-2-3[4-5]-
 0--[2---4]-

 0-1-2-3-4[5-6]-
 0---2--[4---6]-

 ...
```

EDIT2: My example above does imply the timing of the emissions, just as @akarnokd suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32813472/3123541). However, I still don't know how to archive such scenario. Would be great is someone can give another example of `join` without using `timer` or `interval`?

Answer (score 1):

The operator combines values from the two sources: whenever the left fires, the left value is combined with all currently open right values. The same is true for the opposite firing mode.

> Is it possible to join two sequences using count instead of duration? The operator window can be defined using either count or time.

I'm not sure what it means to have a count, but you could publish one of the sources and have a take on it:

```
left.publish(o -> o.join(right, lv -> o.take(5), rv -> ..., (a, b) -> a + b);
```

> What type of Observables returned by leftDurationSelector and rightDurationSelector? The names suggest that they should be time related, but the signatures seem to allow any kind of Observable.

By the duration selectors, it doesn't matter what the type is or what values are emitted because the first onNext or onCompleted will signal the end of a particular window. So in a sense, the timing of the event emission matters, but it does not need to be a interval().

Comment: Your last sentence does clarify something to me, but I'm still not clear. I've edited my question, could you elaborate more? Thank you.